# Determine P and Q for P -> Q : T

Tags: logic

Need to determine the truth table for `P` and `Q` in the expression `P -> Q : T`.

What is not clear to me is the behavior of the attribution `: T`.

Is that by discarding all `(P -> Q)` that resolves to `F`?

```
(P -> Q) : T

| P | Q | P -> Q |
------------------
| T | T |    T   |
| F | T |    T   |
| F | F |    T   |
```

Or by discarding all `Q` that resolves to `F`?

```
P -> (Q : T)

| P | Q | P -> Q |
------------------
| T | T |    T   |
| F | T |    T   |
```

### Edit

Just to clarify, this would be the full truth table I'm talking about:

```
P -> Q

| P | Q | P -> Q |
------------------
| T | T |    T   |
| T | F |    F   |
| F | T |    T   |
| F | F |    T   |
```

Comment: Not very clear, but IMO it is the first one: which are the rows in the t-t for $P \to Q$ corresponding to TRUE ?

Comment: Thanks @Mauro. You answer alongside [this resource](https://www.shaalaa.com/question-bank-solutions/if-p-q-f-p-q-f-then-truth-value-p-q-mathematical-logic-truth-value-statement-logic_678), did put some lights on it. I'm gonna go with the first alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Got to an answer through @Mauro's comment and [this resource](https://www.shaalaa.com/question-bank-solutions/if-p-q-f-p-q-f-then-truth-value-p-q-mathematical-logic-truth-value-statement-logic_678).

From my own example, the answer is the first one:

```
(P -> Q) : T

| P | Q | P -> Q |
------------------
| T | T |    T   |
| F | T |    T   |
| F | F |    T   |
```

The line that should be removed from the whole truth table is:

```
  | P | Q | P -> Q |
  ------------------
  | T | T |    T   | <- result is true, need to be kept
- | T | F |    F   | <- result is false,needs to be removed
  | F | T |    T   | <- result is true, need to be kept
  | F | F |    T   | <- result is true, need to be kept
```